# Get excel worksheet from workbook and send it as email attachment

Tags: c#

can anyone help me on how can i get the excel worksheet and send it as attachment. The code for email is already good, my only problem is to get the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EPPLUS](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started) to achieve this pretty straight forward. Here's a code snippet 
from their documentation on github.

```
   //Open the workbook (or create it if it doesn't exist)
    var fi=new FileInfo(@"c:\workbooks\myworkbook.xlsx")
    using (var p = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
       var ws=p.Workbook.Worksheets["MyWorksheetName"];

       //Save and close the package.
       p.Save();
    }
```

Comment: i run it, but where the file will go?

Comment: Like the comment says: " //Open the workbook (or create it if it doesn't exist)"
It will be opened from/saved to "@"c:\workbooks\myworkbook.xlsx" in this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void sendMail()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mail sending...");
        MailMessage ePosta = new MailMessage();
        ePosta.From = new MailAddress("From mail adress");
        ePosta.To.Add("To Mail Adress");
        ePosta.CC.Add("CCmail adress (optional)")

        ePosta.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:/xx/yy/abc.xlsx"));
        ePosta.Subject = "Subject here"
        ePosta.Body = "Body Message here"
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(From mail adress, From mail password);
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        object userState = ePosta;
        try
        {
            smtp.SendAsync(ePosta, (object)ePosta);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mail sending error");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Mail sent");
```

Comment: this isnt the same thing...it creates a spreadsheet from a listview...the questioner mentions nothing like that

Comment: If he want to just add an excel as an attachment change send mail function line: 
              ePosta.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:/xxx/xxx/xx.xls)); I edited my answer like he wants. Thanks

Comment: he only wants a single sheet from the workbook though